# How to store global variables in Angular 8? For example UUID, to be used on requests/services?

Tags: angular

So I have an app, that will do the following:
As soon as the user enters:

will call SendImpression()

That function will send the screen height and width, and on the API side, data like the IP, timestamp, and a UUID will be stored in the database, then that UUID will be returned on that same request,

What I want to do next, is save that UUID in a global manner, so on the next requests that I need to do I can reuse that UUID variable,

I will need that variable on services, for example imagine I have a UserOptin service, and I would need to send the UUID along with the user Optin, and imagine I have other services that also need that UUID, what is the best way to procceed / store this UUID ?

Thanks!

Comment: create a global `ConfigService`. Have you tried this ?

Comment: In my case I would go for localstorage.

Comment: Yes. In ConfigService you can create a logic where, store it in localstorage if it's not available. If it's there, return it

Comment: The easiest way would be to go with local storage.

Comment: easy example : https://therichpost.com/how-to-store-global-variables-in-angular-9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use service and localStorage as way [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xuxcsd)

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from '../models/config';
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService{
    setConfig(config: Config){
        sessionStorage.setItem("pa_config",JSON.stringify(config))    
    }  
    removeConfig(){
        sessionStorage.removeItem("pa_config");
    }
    getConfig(){
        let config:Config=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("pa_config"));
        return  config || new Config();
    }              
}
```

put in AppModule in providers

```
providers: [ConfigService],
```

create your config class

```
export class Config{
   public UUID:string="";
  //.. add your generals here
   constructor(){}
}
```

before set data firstly get from service then set your config item in it.

Example in component.ts

```
constructor(private _config:ConfigService) { }
```

in your function

```
let config=this._config.getConfig();
config.UUID="test";
this._config.setConfig(config);
```